# DateTime in FUNC<>

Tags: c#, func

I have this:

```
Func<DateTime> getDateTime = () => DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(getDateTime);
```

But as output I get this:

```
System.Func`1[System.DateTime]
```

How to get the current time back?

Comment: You're not invoking the func. You're just calling its ToString() method.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(getDateTime());`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(obj)` is same as `obj.ToString()` to reference type which returns type name instead of its value.

Answer (score 5):

You need to invoke the lambda expression instead like this to print the current timestamp:

```
 Func<DateTime> getDateTime = () => DateTime.Now;
 Console.WriteLine(getDateTime());
```

It prints below output on console:

```
20-07-2017 15:46:10
```

The `getDateTime` variable is of delegate type which points to a function (a lambda expression in this case). The back-tick in your current output `` System.Func`1[System.DateTime] `` is indicative that it is a generic based delegate.

`Console.WriteLine` method doesn't have any overload which takes parameter of delegate type so it simply calls `getDateTime.ToString()` to produce your current output in place of invoking the function pointed by the delegate.

Comment: Thank you nice, ok. also nice

Comment: You're welcome. That's great. You can select any of the answers as accepted answers by clicking the green check mark below the voting buttons. This helps the community to focus on unanswered questions.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't calling the `Func<>` as a method, but rather its `implicit ToString()` method.

To fix this, simply add the empty method brackets `()` after your method call.

```
Console.WriteLine(getDateTime());
```